# OAuth 2.0 3-legged flow - handling with Scala Play WS client

Tags: scala, model-view-controller, oauth-2.0, playframework, webservice-client

I am trying to handle the **OAuth 2.0 3-legged** flow with **Web Service Client** in **Scala Play** in a **MVC** architecture project.

So basically in a 3-legged flow initially (by passing client id, client secret and redirect URIs) we receive a grant token with which we can fetch the access token and the refresh token to access the data resources.

The above *grant token is received in the redirect URL after successful login* to the site.

How to fetch the grant token from the redirect url after successful login? Any form of help is appreciated as in a flowchart, description or code snippet.